# Jenkins - Block "Execute shell"

Tags: shell, jenkins

We are using Jenkins for a variety of jobs, including both building and testing, with different developers having access only to the jobs within their scope.

However, when we are allowing a Jenkins user to "Configure" the job, we are basically permitting them to run shell (via the "Execute shell" step) with the privileges of the user who is running the Jenkins binary. That, in turn, gives theoretical ability to change things on the server and access files they are not supposed to.

Question: How can we control that?

So basically, I am looking for a way to disable the ability of users to edit the existing shell fields of particular builds (or altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that we ended up implementing is a master-slave tandem, where the master node has the number of executors set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround that I haven't personally tested, you can overwrite the `sh` executable used by Jenkins in the global settings, but then everyone won't be able to use "Execute Shell".

You could then have some programmers write plugins for actions that you DO allow.